# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/TilesApplicationContext Error with Spring Servlet

Tags: java, apache, maven, spring-mvc, tiles

I am trying a helloworld application with spring mvc with apache tiles. While I am deploying my application, tomcat failed to deploy my app by showing following error:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/TilesApplicationContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:606)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:518)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:504)
```

I used tiles 3.0 and in added tiles-config3.0 in my tiles.xml configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>  
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
  "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 3.0//EN" 
  "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_3_0.dtd">
```

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you tell me what I am missing here ?
your suggestion will be appreciated. :)

Comment: It seems that your tiles jars are not been deployed with your app.

Comment: I have pasted it in WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: It is a bit too late probably, but TilesApplicationContext belongs to Tiles 2, not Tiles 3. You probably have the wrong dependency somewhere. Maybe one of your views is using `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView` instead of `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView`

Comment: incorrect version or another version of Tiles in Spring-webflow 2.4.x can interfere. Need to check and exclude the older TIles. The Spring-webflow 2.5.1 has Tiles3.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these dependencies as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
    <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If not resolved try `<scope>runtime</scope>` for your `tiles` dependencies in `pom.xml`